# 3D interpolation between tabulated values in R

Tags: r, interpolation, lookup

I want to interpolate between values of a table with three independent variable. Here is a small portion of the table: [Part of Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSE8G.png). The independent variables are t/R, a/c and a/t. The table provides a set of 7 coefficients, namely A0 through A6 which are used to calculated four G-values (G0, G1, G5 and G6). So calculating each G-Value requires all the respective seven A-coefficients. The goal is to interpolated between the tabulated values for each A when t/R, a/c and a/t are in-between the grid values. The tabulated values for t/R and a/c are not equally spaced. Is there any function in R which can do this automatically?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `approx3d` in package `oce`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is there some function that the values in the table are derived from? If so, recalculate from that formula is better than an interpolation? Or apply some multiple regression models and see if they fit well enough?